# Is there a non parametric test to apply for design with 2 factors in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 2 groups: treatment and time of day. 'Treatment' has 2 levels, 'time of the day' has 7. I want to test if the measured response differs for each treatment and time of the day, and test for the interaction between these two factors.

Can I use a Kruskal Wallis or is there a better way?

Comment: Repeated measures ANOVA could be used if hypotheses are correct but it's more a statistical question than an R question

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about the appropriate use of various statistical methods, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.